# Using and interpreting nested manova in R

Tags: r, manova, nested-data, nested-models

I have measured the concentration of 7 elements in 30 `Lake`s. I have between 8 and 12 observations per `Lake` (i.e., I measured the concentration of all 7 elements upon each observation). I took more than one observation per `Lake` to account for within `Lake` variability. These `Lakes` can be classified into 3 nested grouping variables: `Lake` is nested within `State` which is nested within `Region`. My goal is to see if there is a difference in chemistry between each of the grouping variable, which elements are different between them, and which grouping variable best describes the variance between `Lakes`. My data is set up like this:

```r
Lake  State  Region  Measure   Elm1   Elm2   Elm3   Elm4   Elm5   Elm6   Elm7
a      WY      2       1        …     …
```

Where `Measure` is the unique ID number for each of the 8-12 measurements per lake. This is a unique number throughout the dataset, so there is only 1 observation where `Measure` == 1.

I am having trouble finding an example that is similar to my design. How can I specify a nested manova model for this kind of design in R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fit a model something like

```
mod <- lm(cbind(Elm1,Elm2,Elm3,Elm4,Elm5,Elm6,Elm7) ~ Region / State / Lake, data = dat)
```

Get omnibus tests from `manova()` and post-hoc comparisons using the **emmeans** package. e.g.

```
library(emmeans)
emm <- emmeans(mod, ~ Region | Elt, mult.name = "Elm")
emm
pairs(emm)
```

Comment: could you clarify how you would specify this if the elements had names of different lengths, like Magnesium, Manganese, ect.. instead of `Elmx` like in my example

Comment: Use the actual variable names. You can choose what you want for mult.name, but change it both places.